# Let $G$ be a group and $H\unlhd G$ with $|H|=25$. Also $G/H \cong A_4$. How many subgroups of order $75$ in $G$? And order $100$? How many are normal?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a normal subgroup with $|H| = 25$. Also we know that $G/H \cong A_4$.

I want to find out answers for these 2 questions:

1. How many subgroups of order 75 in $G$?
2. How many subgroups of order 100 in $G$? And how many of them are normal?

Here's what I found about that:

By the Lagrange theorem we can say that $|G| = 300$ (Because $|G| = |H||G/H|)$.

By the same reason for every $H'$ such that $|H'| = 75$ we can say that $|G/H| = 4$ (May be we can say that there's not many groups or order 4 for answer the 1'st question).

Second fact I think we can use is that order of every $g \in G$ is divisor of 300. And may be exist some pretty easy proof based on number theory.

Comment: If you know Sylow theorems, then you are done

Comment: I have read very little about them, and some things are not entirely obvious to me. This is largely why I asked this question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Sylow's Theorem. If $H$ is a normal subgroup with order coprime to its index in $G$, then every subgroup of $G$ of order a multiple of $H$ must contain $H$.

Hint: $|NX:N|=|X:X\cap N|$.

So all the subgroups you are asked about must contain $H$, and you can use the correspondence theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this problem without thinking much, probably from Sylow theorems you'll get that $H$ is the only subgroup of order 25, so any subgroup $K$ of $G$ with order divisible by 25 will contain $H$, thus will correspond to $K/H$, which is a subgroup of $G/H$. So we just need the number of respective subgroups of $A_4$.

Comment: Could you tell me more about your solution? I'm not quite familiar with the concepts of Silov's subgroups, and I'm not quite able to understand some of the transitions even after reading the materials.

Comment: Since $25=5^2 \mid 300$ and $5^3 \not \mid 300$, first Sylow theorem tells us that $G$ has a subgroup of order 25 (we already know that, it is $H$). Second Sylow theorem tells us, that all such groups are conjugate to each other – in particular here, since $H$ is normal, it's the only such group. For any subgroup $K$ of $G$, if it has order divisible by $25$, from first Sylow theorem it has to have subgroup of order 25 – but we know the only possibility is $H$, so $H<K<G$. Now we have bijection between subgroups $K<G$ containing $H$ and subgroups of $G/H$ (given by taking quotient by $H$).